# In R, how can I get the value of an addition rather than NA

Tags: r

In the following example, I want the value of the addition rather than `NA`. How can I do that?

```
set.seed(7354)
a <-  rbinom(1,1,.5)
x <-  ifelse(a==0, rexp(1, 1/50), NA )
y <-  ifelse(a==1, rexp(1, 1/100), NA)
b <- ifelse(a==1, rbinom(1,1,.5), NA)
z1 <- ifelse(b==1, rexp(1, 1/100), NA)
z2 <- ifelse(b==0, rexp(1, 1/190), NA)
s <- (1-a)*x + a *(y + b * z1 + (1-b) * z2)
```

My desired output is `s = 968.8501`.

Comment: Is there a reason you use NA rather than 0?

Comment: @HongOoi For `b` I cannot use 0.  If  `b` becomes NA, then `s` will also NA.

Comment: @HongOoi `b` is a binary variable and it is generated if and only if `a=1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
s = c( (1-a)*x, a*y, a*b*z1, a*(1-b)*z2 )
s = sum(s, na.rm = T)
```

This will let you have NAs but they will not affect the sum of terms that are not.

Answer (score 1):

```
set.seed(7354)

a <- rbinom(1,1,.5)
x <- (a==0) * rexp(1, 1/50)
y <- (a==1) * rexp(1, 1/100)
b <- (a==1) * rbinom(1,1,.5)
z1 <- (b==1) * rexp(1, 1/100)
z2 <- (b==0) * rexp(1, 1/190)

(1-a)*x + a *(y + b * z1 + (1-b) * z2)
# [1] 968.8501
```

If you're doing this as part of a simulation or bootstrapping loop, this will be *much* faster than a bunch of `ifelse`s.

Comment: `b` is generated only if `a=1` and `b` is a binary variable that can take value 0 or 1. I am confused whether I will take 0 value for `b` if `a=0` or I will take NA for `b` if `a=0`.

Comment: If a=0, it doesn't matter what b is, because that part of the sum will be zeroed out anyway.

Comment: All that's required is that b is not NA.

Comment: yes, you are right. `If a=0, it doesn't matter what b is, because that part of the sum will be zeroed out anyway.` But for the whole analysis, I am not pretty sure yet whether I can mix up the 0 of `b` from `a=0` and 0 of of `b` from `a=1`. Btw, I didn't know the faster way that can be used instead of `ifelse`. Thanks.